# Boolean Exercise

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

It asks me to find the POS synthesis (the correct answer is C). First of all I wrote $(X_0'X_2')+(X_2X_3'X_1')$. Then I tried with DeMorgan and I got $(X_0+X_2)(X_2'+X_3+X_1)$. Now the only thing I thought to do was to multiply all those variables, but by doing that I'm again getting a SOP synthesis. What can I do?

[image]

Comment: You could always just try each of the answer choices and use a truth table to test equivalence.